# Documentum find out which ADTS is processing renditon

Tags: instance, documentum

I have 2 instances of ADTS servers for 1 docbase and would like to find out which one processed my renditions.

I would like to know which renditions have been done by RenderServer1 and which have been done by RenderServer2

The 2 instances are set as cts_instance_info and and I know each one is working as I can check logs.

Does someone have an idea?

Thanks,
Stéphane

Comment: You could look on the actual ADTS servers for the processed files.  The files should be in a completed folder somewhere (it has been a while since I used ADTS).